# Convert timezone naive datetime string to UTC datetime (but not using pytz)

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

We have the need to convert an incoming datetime string into a UTC datetime string. The incoming string is in this format:

```
'01/28/2022 12:00 AM'
```

with intended output as:

```
'2022-01-28T08:00:00Z'
```

The string has no declared timezone but is supposed to be PST. We'd like to code this in a way that allows for multiple timezones and date string formats. We can get this working using the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

UTC_TIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
PROVIDER_DATETIME_FORMAT = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'
PROVIDER_TIMEZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

def dt_string_to_utc_converter(datetime_str)
    utc_timezone = pytz.utc
    pst_timezone = pytz.timezone(PROVIDER_TIMEZONE)

    naive_date = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, PROVIDER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
    pst_date = pst_timezone.localize(naive_date)
    utc_date = pst_date.astimezone(utc_timezone)
    utc_date_str = utc_date.strftime(UTC_TIME_FORMAT)

    return utc_date_str
```

However (for reasons I won't get into) we have been asked to not use the pytz library and instead stick to Python's native datetime, and dateutil libraries. Currently we are committed to Python 3.8.

I've tried a number of things things using datetime's strptime and dateutil's parser, but all to dead ends so far. Are there any obvious patterns i am missing?

Thanks

Comment: with the input as `s = '01/28/2022 12:00 AM'` what is the intended output?

Comment: I don't think I understand what your trying to do because why not just do `s = s[:10] + str(int(s[11:13]) + 8) + s[13:]`?

Comment: Have updated question to better explain intended output. Also we want to code generically enough that we could potentially handle datetime strings in other formats as well as other timezones.

Comment: Are you allowed to use pandas? Can you consider to upgrade python version above 3.9.4 which is a good idea in term of security? See https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-10210/product_id-18230/Python-Python.html

Comment: Unfortunately Pandas is also not an option.

Answer (score 1):

for the record, here's an option using Python 3.9's [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) and Python 3.7's [isoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat).

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

def to_isoformat(s, tzname, inputformat='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'):
    """
    convert an input string "s" representing date/time in format "inputformat" in
    time zone "tzname" to UTC and return an ISO format string with Z denoting UTC.

    Parameters
    ----------
    s : str
        string representing date/time.
    tzname : str
        IANA time zone name of time zone that s belongs in.
    inputformat : str, optional
        date/time string format. The default is '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'.

    Returns
    -------
    str
        ISO format string, with seconds precision and Z denoting UTC.

    """
    # to datetime and set time zone
    dt = datetime.strptime(s, inputformat).replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo(tzname))
    # convert to UTC and make ISO format with Z for UTC
    return dt.astimezone(ZoneInfo("UTC")).isoformat(timespec='seconds').replace('+00:00', 'Z')
    

print(to_isoformat('01/28/2022 12:00 AM', 'America/Los_Angeles'))
# 2022-01-28T08:00:00Z
```

With Python 3.8, you can basically just replace `from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo` with `from dateutil.tz import gettz as ZoneInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some more digging I managed to find refs [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/8fve1g/do_i_need_pytz/) and [here](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/dateutil.utils.default_tzinfo) that laid out the basics of what I needed. Final code looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz, parser, utils

UTC_TIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
PROVIDER_TIMEZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

def dt_string_to_utc_converter(datetime_str)
    parsed_dt = parser.parse(datetime_str)
    localized_dt = utils.default_tzinfo(parsed_dt, tz.gettz(PROVIDER_TIMEZONE))
    utc_dt = localized_dt.astimezone(tz.tzutc())
    utc_dt_str = utc_dt.strftime(UTC_TIME_FORMAT)
```

Comment: Once you update to Python 3.9, you have `zoneinfo` in the standard library. It's easier to transition if you use dateutil instead of pytz before. Btw. I think you don't have to use `utils.default_tzinfo`, you can just `replace` the tzinfo object (which I think is more readable).

Comment: I enviously looked at the 3.9 zoneinfo capabilities and thought "so close...". Thanks for the confirmation!